# jQuery: mouseover function not triggering for unordered list descendant

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, anchor, mouseover

I have an unordered list as below:

```
<ul id="dasList">
 <li id="dasListItem1">
  <span>
   <div style="height:10px">
     <label id="dasLabel1">LaLaLa</label>
   </div>
   <a id="dasAnchor1"></a>
  </span>
 </li>
 <li id="dasListItem2">
  <span>
   <div style="height:10px">
     <label id="dasLabel2">LaLaLa</label>
   </div>
   <a id="dasAnchor2"></a>
  </span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Now here is what i want to do. I want to trigger a mouseover function on the anchor tag contained in the list item. Currently, I'm using this:

```
$("#dasList a").mouseover(function(){
        alert('i find your lack of faith disturbing');
    });
```

But for some ungodly reason, it isn't triggering. I have placed break-points as well, but to no avail :(

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! It was a problem with my browser :) Apparently the latest Chrome update seems to recognize the mouseover as mouseclick when the chrome dev tool is open :/

Honestly, a very weird scenario, and something I'd never expect. Am finally closing this question, as I think it's about time I did!

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
 $("#dasList li a").mouseover(function(){
   ...
```

**using find()**

```
 $("#dasLis").find("a").mouseover(function(){
```

**using attribute selector with `^`** which select all element beginning with the provided string

```
 $("a[id^='dasAnchor']").mouseover(function(){
```

Comment: The function seems to get triggered only on a click on the list-item.

Comment: I know :/ well, i can't post the exact code. The code in the question is a stripped down version of it..